# SQL Query returning column 'id' not found in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "select re.id,re.external_ref_no ,re.tr_date ,re.event_start_time ,re.event_end_time ,re.status ,\n" +
        "re.event_data_link ,re.created_at ,re.created_by ,re.last_updated_at ,re.last_updated_by  \n" +
        "from  report_master rm join report_event re on rm.id=re.report_id join event_report_mapping_ erm on re.id =erm.event_id " +
        "   where re.report_id =?1 and re.external_ref_no =?2 and re.tr_date =?3 and re.service_name=?4", nativeQuery = true)
ReportEventModel findEventByExternalRefNoAndTrDate1(Long reportId, String externalRefNo, String trDate
        , String serviceName);
```

2022-09-12 14:26:45.029 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([name4_5_] : [VARCHAR]) - [HOURLY-EARLY-PAYIN1]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.033 DEBUG (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [org.hibernate.SQL]
select
re.id,
re.external_ref_no ,
re.tr_date ,
re.event_start_time ,
re.event_end_time ,
re.status ,
re.event_data_link ,
re.created_at ,
re.created_by ,
re.last_updated_at ,
re.last_updated_by
from
report_master rm
join
report_event re
on rm.id=re.report_id
join
event_report_mapping_ erm
on re.id =erm.event_id
where
re.report_id =?
and re.external_ref_no =?
and re.tr_date =?
and re.service_name=?
2022-09-12 14:26:45.037 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [61]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.039 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [8a34c]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.039 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [2021-12-24]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.039 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [BOGS]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.042 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([id] : [BIGINT]) - [50]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.047 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([created_at] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2022-09-12 14:25:58.0]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.048 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([created_by] : [VARCHAR]) - [Manish]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.048 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([event_data_link] : [VARCHAR]) - [HOURLY-EARLY-PAYIN1/2021-12-24/8a34c]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.048 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([external_ref_no] : [VARCHAR]) - [8a34c]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.050 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([last_updated_at] : [VARCHAR]) - [2022-09-12 14:25:58]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.050 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([last_updated_by] : [VARCHAR]) - [Manish]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.050 TRACE (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor] extracted value ([event_end_time] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [null]
2022-09-12 14:26:45.056 WARN (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2022-09-12 14:26:45.056 ERROR (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] Column 'report_id' not found.
2022-09-12 14:26:45.078 ERROR (qtp952590825-41) trkId=123123132123 [c.u.b.server.advisor.ExceptionAdvisor] Exception occurred.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select re.id,re.external_ref_no ,re.tr_date ,re.event_start_time ,re.event_end_time ,re.status ,
re.event_data_link ,re.created_at ,re.created_by ,re.last_updated_at ,re.last_updated_by
from  report_master rm join report_event re on rm.id=re.report_id join event_report_mapping_ erm on re.id =erm.event_id    where re.report_id =? and re.external_ref_no =? and re.tr_date =? and re.service_name=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all data are not properly mapped. As seen in logs data is also retrieved from the database.
Add report_id in the Select clause of SQL Query and try.
Try Using this:

```
"select re.id,re.external_ref_no ,re.tr_date ,re.event_start_time ,re.event_end_time ,re.status ,\n" +
    "re.event_data_link ,re.created_at ,re.created_by ,re.last_updated_at ,re.last_updated_by, re.report_id  \n" +
    "from report_event re join report_master rm on rm.id=re.report_id join event_report_mapping_ erm on re.id =erm.event_id " +
    "   where re.report_id =?1 and re.external_ref_no =?2 and re.tr_date =?3 and re.service_name=?4"
```